# AWS EB .ebextensions - Contains invalid key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have the following config file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    at: []

01_remove_old_cron_jobs:
  command: "sudo cp enable_mod_pagespeed.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d"
02_remove_old_cron_jobs:
  command: "sudo rpm -U -iv --replacepkgs mod-pagespeed.rpm"
03_remove_old_cron_jobs:
  command: "sudo touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush"
```

Labeled `01.config`. When I deploy this to my server, I get an error such as:

```
Error processing file (Skipping): '.ebextensions/01.config' - Contains invalid key: '02_remove_old_cron_jobs'. For information about valid keys, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html
```

However, the documentation contains no information about valid keys, and this key looks similar to my other keys.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration files keys are specified in this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

> Configuration files support the following keys that affect the Linux server your application runs on.
>
> Keys:
>
> - Packages
> - Groups
> - Users
> - Sources
> - Files
> - Commands
> - Services
> - Container Commands
>
> Keys are processed in the order that they are listed above.

So, in your case, you have to write your commands inside a `commands` key. Your file will look like that:

```
commands:
  01_remove_old_cron_jobs:
    command: "sudo cp enable_mod_pagespeed.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d"
  02_remove_old_cron_jobs:
    command: "sudo rpm -U -iv --replacepkgs mod-pagespeed.rpm"
  03_remove_old_cron_jobs:
    command: "sudo touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush"
```

The complete syntax for commands you can find here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands

Answer (score 1):

you config file is not formatted correctly:

packages:

yum:

at: []

commands:  <----- MISSING HERE -------------------------------------------X

01_remove_old_cron_jobs:

command: "sudo cp enable_mod_pagespeed.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d"

02_remove_old_cron_jobs:

command: "sudo rpm -U -iv --replacepkgs mod-pagespeed.rpm"

03_remove_old_cron_jobs:

command: "sudo touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush"

Comment: Please consider formatting your answer using code quotes !